# Connecting SqlAzure database in conventional way

Tags: database, web-applications, silverlight-3.0, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to know , can I connect to my Sql Azure database as we connect with our general Sql Server 8/9/10 databases, via Silverlight -WCF or ASP.Net or Winform App.

My development environment is WinXP with SP3 / VS 2008 Professional. I am asking so while installing Windows Azure SDK and Toolkit i got Platform incompatibility error that is it will require Vista 32/64 bit and above or Win 2008.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to connect to SQL Azure you just need the right connection string (and to set the SQL Azure firewall to allow connections from your IP address).

You won't be able to install the Windows Azure SDK without Windows Vista, Windows 7, or Windows Server 2008, but you don't need Windows Azure to use SQL Azure.